# Django ModelAdmin response_change method

Tags: django, django-admin

I've found that the response_change method on admin.ModelAdmin to be very useful -- yet I don't believe it is documented in the Django docs at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-methods.  Is the source code the only location for details?  If so, where is it?  I looked here: https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/admin but did not find anything...

An example of its effective use is here: http://brandonkonkle.com/blog/2010/oct/4/django-admin-customization-examples/.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find it here: 
[https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/20ba3ce4ac8e8438070568ffba76f7d8d4986a53/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1234)

django.contrib.admin is a strange beast since it contains a lot of utility functions, that might be useful for general django but are for its internal use. This means that they might go away or change between releases and you can't relay on it especially until it makes into core django (or just be prepare to cover it with yout tests).

Comment: Thanks!  Is there a preferred API to use that fits where response_change currently works?

Comment: I don't think so. I think you're good as long as you use tests.

Comment: Agreed.  I also use buildout and pin the version of Django I'm using.